# How to open to an existing tab in safari with an html 'a' link?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, ipad

From Safari I can launch another app with:

```
<a href="webbrowserapp://example.com/open?url=http.....">Open WebBrowserApp</a>
```

But I can't seem to return to Safari with:

```
<a href="safari://">Return to Safari</a>
```

If possible I'd like to return to the tab I came from.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Found this info: https://www.itworld.com/article/3008858/how-to-open-specific-web-browsers-using-hyperlinks.html Which does indicate you can open with the modifier like:  <a href="microsoft-edge:http://google.com">Google in Edge</a>, still not finding a way to specify a particular tab.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that.... You can not open safari using

```
Safari://
```

Well... you can not open safari on iOS using another browser..... so that means you cannot achieve what you are looking for... even in iOS 13 and I don’t think Apple is gonna implement that anytime soon....
So you can use any other browser like:

Firefox: `<a href="Firefox://">Return to Firefox</a>`

Google Chrome: `<a href=“GoogleChrome://“>Return To Chrome</a>`

And I am sure there are many other great alternatives.... Goodluck!